# Inserting data into file bash using sed

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed, awk

I am trying to insert data into a file using a bash script.

The format of the file is like this 
 (constant)  (variable)  (constant)

My bash script is as follows

```
#Processing other data by matching a string.
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print}' keys.txt hellos.txt | awk -v OFS=',' '{print $2,$3}' | xargs -n1 ipset -! add allowed_hosts

#Now do the same command again, but only get the matching string.
#Match a strings from these two files and put in the variable "line".

line=$(awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print}' keys.txt hellos.txt | awk -v OFS=' ' '{print $1}')

#For each string matched, insert it into a text file.

for word in $line
do 

#The sed command to insert text into a file with format 
#<string> <word (a single word from the line variable)> <string>

<strike> sed -i '$ a CLIENT_RANDOM $word 010111010011011010' output.txt </strike>

# Changed the sed statement to use printf
printf 'CLIENT_RANDOM %s "$word" 010111010011011010\n' > output.txt

done
```

For some reason, the script does not print to the file. Can someone please help solve this.

Sample files for keys.txt and hellos.txt used in the first file are here

keys.txt: http://pastebin.com/bYkJZuiL
hellos.txt: http://pastebin.com/6WvXG9yd

Alternatively, Can I insert data doing it in the first line itself. This would avoid the for loop and creating a variable altogether.

i.e I would like to insert data into a file using this one command

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print}' keys.txt hellos.txt | awk -v OFS=',' '{print $2,$3}' | xargs -n1 ipset -! add allowed_hosts
```

Sample Output file (output.txt)

```
CLIENT_RANDOM <first word from line> 010111010011011010'
CLIENT_RANDOM <second word from line>  010111010011011010'
CLIENT_RANDOM <third word from line> 010111010011011010'
CLIENT_RANDOM <fourth word from line>  010111010011011010'
```

So if the variable $line outputs "This is a fox" The output.txt file will be like

```
CLIENT_RANDOM This 010111010011011010'
CLIENT_RANDOM is 010111010011011010'
CLIENT_RANDOM a 010111010011011010'
CLIENT_RANDOM fox  010111010011011010'
```

Edit: I was able to solve the first part of the problem. I can not print the statements to output.txt in the required format. However, I am still not able to combine it do it all in one loop.

Comment: When you run `sed -i 'COMMAND-STRING' FILENAME`, the `-i` means "in-place". That means the specified `FILENAME` is both the input and the output file. I believe this is not intended here, although I don't completely understand what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I want to take a word from the line and append some text before and after it and store the entire thing in output.txt. I just tried it without the -i option.

Comment: Repeat the same thing for all the "words" in the $line variable.  The words in line are separated by a space delimiter.

Comment: Can you give an example output (just two or three lines) how output.txt would have to look? I don't know awk, but I'm sure there is a simpler way, so if you could explain what exactly you want to have in the end, we'll surely find a solution.

Comment: Your variable can't be expanded within single quotes... I don't understand your question, but you will need double quotes instead for that...

Comment: Please see attached output file. Hope that helps explain better.

Comment: I tried to use printf instead of sed and it works for now, however, I would still like to get it done in one loop.